# Brandmeister API - How to get the Last Heard from the API

Tags: software-development, dmr, brandmeister

Using the API and looking thru the documentation I can't find anywhere how to pull the LastHeard that is on the LastHeard pages. https://brandmeister.network/index.php?page=lh

Docs
https://api.brandmeister.network/docs/

API
https://api.brandmeister.network/v2/

Example Device: https://api.brandmeister.network/v2/device/byCall?callsign=ad5qa

ID Stats: https://api.brandmeister.network/v2/stats/3197083
But they confirmed this is not last heard and the datetime never changes

```
{
    "lastHeard": {
        "repeater": "AD5QA",
        "datetime": 1673989309
    },
    "txTimeThisWeek": "33"
}
```

https://api.brandmeister.network/v2/user/byCall/ad5qa

```
{
        "username": "AD5QA",
        "name": "Thomas",
        "isActive": false,
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lastLogin": false
    }
```

Anyone have any tips to get last heard or derive it from some information.

My workaround if nothing else is found to take the txTimeThisWeek and if it changes log the DateTime of the change and use that as last heard then present 30m, 60m, 120m since to the users on my site https://ad5qa.com

Comment: your Example Device has a `last_seen` property; is that not what you want?

Comment: They confirmed that is not lastheard despite the field name.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan from BM responded with the API does not provide last heard.

[image]